# automatically login to another website cross domain

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a connection from my website to other 3rd-party websites, they are all separately independent. I noticed that there are some websites provided APIs to access to the users' account by using access token. However, it's not all the websites have similar APIs for me to use, the access token only authorised the permission to take part of information, not showing the users' homepage. Do I have any methods to deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information, are you trying to access all the 3rd-party website with a single sign on credential?

Comment: yes, it's like a general entry for users to login to all the other websites by only accessing to my website.

Comment: To be honest it will be hard to pull off, there are Google and Twitter and Facebook who provide an Oauth authentication. You may want to look into that

Comment: Alternatively, you can look at store the token and Renew it before it expire for those 3rd party site. But this is no small feat